# Is there a way to check if multiple checkboxs are checked and select those?

Tags: javascript

I have a list with names. I want to sort this names if I check there checkbox, but i don't know how to select those checkboxes that are checked and use them.

I tryed to use the checkbox id's to compare them if they where checked, but that did'nt work out :(

Comment: Please include your attempt so far, along with the relevant HTML markup for the checkboxes.

Comment: [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

Comment: Since it is a project at my work, I can not include any code of it bc it contains sensitive information. And :checked is a css class that I can't use in js

Comment: @AlexvonB Create a simplified but run-able version of your code using Stackoverflow's snippet function without any irrelevant parts and without the sensitive information. Also `:checked` can be used with JavaScript, for example with `querySelector(All)`.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, by putting the checked checkboxes in an array and giving the checkboxes an id that contains the name. I can compare the id with the list of names and make out that way what is checked.

```
function box_checked() {
 var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
 var box_array  = [];
 i = 0;
 il = box.length;
 for (;i < il; i += 1) {
  if (box[i].checked) {
   box_array.push(box[i].id);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `const boxList = document.querySelectorAll('.box:checked');` ... or by directly converting it into an array via _Spread Syntax_ ... `const boxArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('.box:checked')];` ... thus the OP might have a look into MDN's **a)** [_"Locating DOM elements using selectors"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) and **b)** [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score -1):

Please include your HTML code or any attempts you made so others can help you.
This is how I do it.

```
let checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=name_of_your_checkbox]:checked")
let checkboxValues = [] // TEMP VARIABLE

// CHECKS IF NO SELECTION MADE
if (Object.keys(checked).length == 0) {
    alert("Please select atleast 1")
    return
}

// PUT THE SELECTED VALUES TO THE TEMP VARIABLE
checked.forEach(r => {
    checkboxValues.push(r.value)
});
```